# Header and multiple detail tables Query issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, master-detail

I have 1 header table (**header**) and multiple detail tables (**detail_aa**, **detail_ab** etc.).

```
create table header (header_id int primary key, header_name varchar(100));
create table detail_aa (detail_aa_id int primary key, detail_aa_name varchar(100), header_id int foreign key references header(header_id));
create table detail_ab (detail_ab_id int primary key, detail_ab_name varchar(100), header_id int foreign key references header(header_id));
```

***Note: 1 specific header_id can only go in only 1 detail table***.

So for example if we have a row header_id = 1 in **header** table then

- either **detail_aa** table will have a row with header_id = 1 or
- **detail_ab** table will have a row with header_id = 1 or
- no detail table will have a row with header_id = 1.

It is not possible that both **detail_aa** and **detail_ab** have rows with header_id = 1.

***Example:***

Table: header

```
header_id header_name
--------- -----------
1         Master_1
2         Master_2
3         Master_3
```

Table: detail_aa

```
detail_aa_id detail_aa_name header_id
------------ -------------- ---------
101          Detail_aa_101  1
```

Table: detail_ab

```
detail_ab_id detail_ab_name header_id
------------ -------------- ---------
45           Detail_ab_45   2
```

I want to write a query which show all header_id, header_name from header table and the corresponding data from the detail table or null if it is not linked:

```
header_id header_name detail_table_name detail_id detail_name
--------- ----------- ----------------- --------- -------------
1         Master_1    detail_aa         101       Detail_aa_101
2         Master_2    detail_ab         45        Detail_ab_45
3         Master_3    null              null      null
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd union the two detail tables first then use a left join to get all header, and then detail if it exists.

```
With Detail as (
SELECT 'detail_aa' as detail_table_name, detail_aa_name as detail_name, Detail_aa_id as Detail_ID
UNION 
SELECT 'detail_bb' as detail_table_name, detail_bb_name as detail_name, Detail_bb_id as Detail_ID)

SELECT H.Header_Id, H.Header_Name, D.*
FROM Header H
LEFT JOIN Detail D
on H.Header_ID = D.Header_ID
```

Comment: [`Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) excludes duplicates while `Union All` allows them. Although _we_ know that duplicates can't possibly occur there is no declaration of that fact that the query optimizer can use. Sure, there are undoubtedly constraints or triggers to prevent anything naughty, but ... .

Comment: True, union all would negate the need for the optimizer to execute the distinct and would result in a performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

Use `left join`:

```
select h.*,
       (case when da.header_id is not null
             then 'detail_aa'
             else 'detail_bb'
        end),
       coalesce(da.detail_id, db.detail_id) as detail_id
       coalesce(da.detail_name, db.detail_name) as detail_name
from header h left join
     detail_aa da
     on h.header_id = da.header_id left join
     detail_bb db
     on h.header_id = db.header_id;
```